# I'm Having some trouble obtaining a new message - Android

Tags: android, firebase

I'm having some trouble obtaining a new message.

So my algorithm works like this. I receive the last message from the chat(in Firebase), and if the last message UserId is not equal to mine than it sets a Boolean(newMessage) to true to make it a new message.

When i click on it, the variable sets to false. However when i re-run the application the Boolean does not stay the same, it just resets itself.

What should i do, to fix this?

Here is the code :

MessengerMessagesFragment.java

```
public class MessengerMessagesFragment extends Fragment{
private static final String TAG = "MessengerMessagesFragme";

private List<User> mUserList;

private static final int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 111;

private ListView mListView;
private ArrayList<String> mUsersInM;

private MessagesListAdapter mAdapter;

User user;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messenger_messages, container, false);
    mListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvMessages);
    mUserList = new ArrayList<>();
    mUsersInM = new ArrayList<>();

    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
        // Start sign in/sign up activity
        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .build(), SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        // User is already signed in, show list of messages
        getUsersInM();
    }

    return view;
}

private void updateUserslist(){
    Log.d(TAG, "updateUsersList: updating users list");

    mAdapter = new MessagesListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_message_listitem, mUserList);

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onItemClick: selected user: " + mUserList.get(position).toString());
            mAdapter.setNewMessage(false);
            Log.e(TAG, "onItemClick: Set new message bool " + mAdapter.isNewMessage());
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ChatActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.intent_user), mUserList.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
private void getMessages(){
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    for(int i = 0; i < mUsersInM.size(); i++){
        final int count = i;
        Query query = reference
                .child(getString(R.string.dbname_users))
                .orderByChild(getString(R.string.field_user_id))
                .equalTo(mUsersInM.get(i));
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    mUserList.add(singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
                }
                if(count >= mUsersInM.size() - 1){
                    updateUserslist();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
private void getUsersInM(){
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference
            .child(getString(R.string.dbname_messages))
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                mUsersInM.add(singleSnapshot.getKey().toString());

                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Message user id: " + mUsersInM.toString() );
            }

            getMessages();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

MessagesListAdapter.java

```
public class MessagesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
private static final String TAG = "MessageListAdapter";

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<User> mUsers = null;
private int layoutResource;
private Context mContext;
private int messagesCount = 0;

DatabaseReference myRef;
public boolean newMessage;

public boolean isNewMessage() {
    return newMessage;
}

public void setNewMessage(boolean newMessage) {
    this.newMessage = newMessage;
}

//private int msgC;
private String userID;

public MessagesListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull List<User> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    mContext = context;
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    //getMessagesCount();
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layoutResource = resource;
    this.mUsers = objects;
}

private static class ViewHolder{
    TextView username, message, timeStamp;
    ImageView profileImage, statusOnline, statusOffline;
    RelativeLayout messageBackground;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {


    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.f_username);
        holder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.m_message);
        holder.profileImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.f_profile_image);
        holder.timeStamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.m_timestamp);
        holder.statusOnline = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_Online);
        holder.statusOffline = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_Offline);
        holder.messageBackground = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RelLayoutMessage);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.username.setText(getItem(position).getUsername());
    //holder.email.setText(getItem(position).getEmail());

    //DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_account_settings))
            .orderByChild(mContext.getString(R.string.field_user_id))
            .equalTo(getItem(position).getUser_id());
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                //Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user: " + singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).toString());

                ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

                imageLoader.displayImage(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).getProfile_photo(),
                        holder.profileImage);
                userID = singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getUser_id();
                boolean is_Online = singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).isOnline();
                if(is_Online == true){
                    holder.statusOnline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.statusOffline.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else if(is_Online == false){
                    holder.statusOnline.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.statusOffline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
            setMessageItemSettings(holder, userID);
            getNewMessage(holder, userID);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    return convertView;
}
private void getNewMessage(final ViewHolder holder, final String user_id){
    Query lastMessageQuery = myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_messages))
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child(user_id).orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    lastMessageQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String messageUid = data.child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_messageUserId)).getValue().toString();
                Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: *************** MESSAGE FROM USER ***************  : " + messageUid + " ====== " + newMessage);
                if(messageUid.equals(user_id)){
                    newMessage = true;
                    Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: *************** NEW MESSAGE FROM USER ***************  : " + messageUid + " ====== " + newMessage);
                    if(newMessage){
                        holder.messageBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b7b7b7"));
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void setMessageItemSettings(final ViewHolder holder, final String user_id){
    Log.e(TAG, "getView: USER ID************************************" + userID);
    Log.e(TAG, "getView: USER ID************************************" + messagesCount);
    //msgC = messagesCount;
    //DatabaseReference databaseReference2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query lastMessageQuery = myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_messages))
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child(user_id).orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    lastMessageQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: THINGS--------------+++ ---" + dataSnapshot.toString());
            Log.e(TAG, "getView: USER ID************************************" + userID);
            Log.e(TAG, "getView: USER ID************************************" + messagesCount);
            //String lastItem = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                try{
                    String mMessage = data.child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_messageText)).getValue().toString();
                    holder.message.setText(mMessage);

                    String mTime = data.child(mContext.getString(R.string.field_messageTime)).getValue().toString();
                    holder.timeStamp.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)", Long.valueOf(mTime)));
                }catch(NullPointerException e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: *************** GETTING MESSAGES FROM USER ARE NULL ***************  : " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //Handle possible errors.
        }
    });
    //Log.d(TAG, "getView: USER ID****************" + userID);
}
```

Firebase Message Structure : [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have fixed it buy putting a new_message variable in user_id node 2(WI8yTLA...) on firebase and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving the `newMessage = true;` statement in somewhere?

Comment: No, its in messageListAdapter